# Explanation of Long Jump to Segment

Tags: assembly

Could someone please explain to me the significance of [line #123 in start.s](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel/blob/master/osfmk/x86_64/start.s#L123)? Please note while reading the code that `KERNEL64_CS` is #defined as 0x08.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It completes the transition to long mode (64-bit mode in the AMD64 architecture) by updating the code segment selector (CS). The reason for this is that it is only possible to modify the code segment selector through a jump, unlike the other segment selectors that can simply be written to.

The segment selectors themselves are offsets into the [Global Descriptor Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Descriptor_Table). Each entry is 8 bytes, so `KERNEL64_CS` (0x08) is the second entry.